# how do in the views when i click to the link in views in the page form was chosen needed category

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4

im noob in the rails 4 , i have posts, posts has_many categories, in the views i have links with categories it looks like this:

```
<ul class="dropdown-menu">
      <% Category.all.each do |category| %>
      <li><%= link_to category.name, new_post_path %> </li>
      <% end %>
    </ul>
```

its render user to the form, its look like this:

```
    <%= form_for current_user.posts.build(params[:post]) do |f| %>
  <%= render 'shared/error_messages', object: f.object %>
  <div class="field">
    <h2>Заполните заявку</h2>
    <div class="text-container">
    <p>
  Мне нужно
    </p>
     <div class="field">
    <p>
    Подробно опишите задание
    </p>
    <%= f.collection_select :category_id, Category.all, :id, :name %>
    <%= f.text_area :content, placeholder: "Compose new micropost..." %>
    <%= f.date_select :date %>
    <%= f.time_select :time %>
  </div>
</div>
  <%= f.submit "Опубликовать", class: "btn btn-large btn-primary" %>
<% end %>
```

and when user choose the category in the

```
<ul class="dropdown-menu">
          <% Category.all.each do |category| %>
          <li><%= link_to category.name, new_post_path %> </li>
          <% end %>
        </ul>
```

in the form page the category is first category, but i need choosen category in the

```
<ul class="dropdown-menu">
              <% Category.all.each do |category| %>
              <li><%= link_to category.name, new_post_path %> </li>
              <% end %>
            </ul>


class PostsController < ApplicationController
 # before_filter :signed_in_user

  def new
  end

  def index
    @posts = Post.all
  end

  def show
    redirect_to root_url
  end

  def create
    @post = current_user.posts.build(post_params)

    if @post.save
      flash[:success] = "Поздравляем Ваше задание опубликованно"
      redirect_to @post
  else
    render 'posts/new'
  end
end

private
  def post_params
    params.require(:post).permit(:content, :date, :time, :category_id)
  end

  def correct_user
      @post = current_user.posts.find_by_id(params[:id])
      redirect_to root_url if @post.nil?
    end
end
```

i work on rails 4.0.0 and ruby 2.0
What i want to do to make this work?
any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are different ways to get this working.

First, you need to pass the `category.id` to the `posts#new` action in your link, so you need something like `<%= link_to category.name, new_post_path(category_id:category.id) %>`.

Then you can set the @post's category_id to that param like this

```
def new
  @post = current_user.posts.new(category_id:params[:category_id])
end
```

That way you can use that `@post` object in your `form_for` call like this

```
<%= form_for @post do |f| %>
```

Then your select field should pick up the right category automaticaly.

Btw, it will also make your form usable in the create action.